# Newly created bitmap always has resolution 120dpi

Tags: c#, resharper, gdi+, gdi, xunit

I'm working on a large solution that does image processing. I have a problem on one of the (unit)test projects.

I have a resource file on disk that has resolution 96dpi / 96dpi. But when I load it using `var img =Image.FromFile(fileName)` I get a bitmap that has `img.VerticalResolution == 120` and `img.HorizontalResolution == 120`.

If I explicitly change the resolution using `((Bitmap)img).SetResolution(96, 96);` the resolution changes to 96.

But then, if I clone it `var img2 = new Bitmap(img)` then  `img2.VerticalResolution == 120` and `img2.HorizontalResolution == 120`

I know that this only happens locally because other people on the team don't have this problem and the test run fine on the CI machines. If I try to replicate this on a console application on my machine I don't have this problem - the image object, created from the same file has vertical resolution and horizontal resolution equal to 96dpi. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

As stated the problem occurs in unit tests. The tests are run in x86 configuration.
If I run them using the default Visual Studio test explorer window the tests pass with success. The problem occurs only when I run the them using the ReSharper test window.

So I did some trials:

- Console app - resolution correct
- Unit tests run from VS Test Explorer - resolution correct
- Unit tests using MSTest run from ReSharper window - resolution correct
- Unit tests using XUnit run from ReSharper window - resolution NOT correct

So the problem is with Resharper/XUnit

Comment: It is quite normal, there are lots of Win10 machines these days that run the monitor at 125% or higher.  The Bitmap constructor you use always creates an image with monitor DPI, not image DPI.  Doesn't matter that much, it is only a reference number that is designed to get the image to display with the same visible size on another machine.  So if you're happy about the way the image shows on your monitor then you wouldn't want to change it.  But if you create UI that runs on those other olden machines then SetResolution() tends to make sense.

Comment: Your screen has 120dpi. Use bitmap.SetResolution dpiX, dpiY) to change that value.

Comment: @HansPassant in a console application I made for testing, loading the same image creates a bitmap with 96dpi. That's what troubles me.